# Disk usage summary per user

Tags: files, zsh, users, disk-usage

Is there a way to get the disk usage per user under a given path? `du` doesn't seem to have an option to aggregate disk usage per user, and `df` only seems to report how much disk is left on the drive.

Can this be done with one command or in a few lines on the shell? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. In case it helps, I use `zsh`.

**Note:** Quotas are not enabled on our filesystem.

Comment: Are quotas enabled on your filesystem?

Comment: @jordanm no. They are not. I will clarify this in the OP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will work with `GNU find` and `awk`:

```
find /path -type f -printf '%u %k\n' | awk '{ 
                                            arr[$1] += $2 
                                        } END { 
                                            for ( i in arr ) { 
                                                print i": "arr[i]"K" 
                                            }
                                        }'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of zsh's `stat` builtin.

```
zmodload zsh/stat
local -a stat
local -A usage
local x
for x in **/*(.); do
  stat -A stat -- $x
  ((usage[$stat[5]] += stat[8]))
done
for x in ${(k)usage}; do
  echo $usage[$x] ${${"$(getent passwd $x)"%%:*}:-$x}
done | sort -k1n
```

(`getent` to retrieve the username from the user ID is specific to Linux, I don't think there's anything for that in zsh.)